# How do I make Eclipse start maximized?

Tags: eclipse, window, maximize

When I use Eclipse, I like to work with the window maximized. I have to maximize it by hand at every startup, though. It doesn't help to change the shortcut to say Run Maximized, because that works only for the initial "which project do you want to open?" window. I don't see anything in Preferences that helps, either.

Any ideas?

Comment: It should remember the window position/size it had when it was closed. I guess I never opened Eclipse enough (once or twice per day) to think the keyboard maximize shortcut was that onerous, though.

Comment: Agreed, it should remember it. It never does so, though.